# Java: Sorting a 2D array by first (int filled) column

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I want to sort an `Object[][]` by the first column which consists of `int`s.
Take, for example, this `array`:

```
Object[][] array = {{1, false, false}, {2, true, false}, {0, true, true}};
```

Now, I want to create a new `array` whose rows are sorted in a way that the first element of each row ascends:

```
Object[][] newArray = ...;
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(newArray));
```

What it should print: `{{0, true, true}, {1, false, false}, {2, true, false}}`

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Arrays.sort(array, new Comparator<Object[]>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(Object[] o1, Object[] o2) {
    Integer i1 = (Integer) (o1[0]);
    Integer i2 = (Integer) (o2[0]);
    return i1.compareTo(i2);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Arrays in java has a sort method that takes in Comparator as 2nd parameter.
You can pass in the parameter to be considered for sorting. In your case, we'll need to sort based on the first parameter of the input 2d array; the solution would look like:

`Arrays.sort(array, Comparator.comparingInt(a -> a[0]));`

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.sort method using a custom comparator as follows

```
Arrays.sort(array, new Comparator<Object[]>() {
       @Override
       public int compare(Object []o1, Object []o2) {
            return (Integer)o1[0] - (Integer)o2[0];
       }
});
```

Comment: The functionality for comparing is implemented in the Integer-Class. So you should not implement your own solution (substraction). Use the compareTo method.